# Rails performance of pluck vs ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-performance

I have been defaulting to using `pluck` when only needing one or two fields, but I recently benchmarked the performance difference, and pluck lost:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1
n = 5000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('Country.all:              ') { n.times { Country.all } }
  x.report('Country.unscoped:         ') { n.times { Country.unscoped } }
  x.report('base priority_order:      ') { n.times { Country.unscoped.with_translations(I18n.locale).order(list_at_top:   :desc).order(:name) } }
  x.report('.includes(:translations): ') { n.times { Country.unscoped.with_translations(I18n.locale).order(list_at_top: :desc).order(:name).includes(:translations) } }
  x.report('.pluck(:name):            ') { n.times { Country.unscoped.with_translations(I18n.locale).order(list_at_top: :desc).order(:name).includes(:translations).pluck(:name) } }
  x.report('.pluck(:name) only:       ') { n.times { Country.unscoped.with_translations(I18n.locale).order(list_at_top: :desc).order(:name).pluck(:name) } }
end

# Results
=begin
                                  user     system      total        real
  Country.all:                0.990000   0.020000   1.010000 (  1.023518)
  Country.unscoped:           0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.050440)
  base priority_order:        1.350000   0.010000   1.360000 (  1.356728)
  .includes(:translations):   1.460000   0.000000   1.460000 (  1.462635)
  .pluck(:name):              8.230000   0.150000   8.380000 ( 11.168291)
  .pluck(:name) only:         6.980000   0.150000   7.130000 (  9.903130) 
=end
```

As you can see, pluck's real time was much slower. I went with the 4th `.includes(:translations)` to avoid N+1 queries (and the first two were really just baselines, didn't provide the data needed).

Is this benchmarking test accurate and pluck really is slower, or is this not telling the whole story? There should be significant memory savings, and some time savings since ActiveRecord objects are not being created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test isn't accurate. `Country.all` isn't actually fetching the rows, it's just going to return an active record relation.  Same with your other scopes.  Only pluck will actually query the data.

I have a countries table with 243 rows.  Not many columns (id, name, iso2, iso3).  I tweaked your queries to `map(&:name)` the first two so the result is the same as the pluck.  Pluck wins by a lot.

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1
  n = 1000
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report('Country.all.map(&:name):      ') { n.times { Country.all.map(&:name) } }
    x.report('Country.unscoped.map(&:name): ') { n.times { Country.unscoped.map(&:name) } }
    x.report('Coutry.pluck(:name):          ') { n.times { Country.unscoped.pluck(:name) } }
  end
```

The output:

```
                                    user     system      total        real
Country.all.map(&:name):        3.830000   0.140000   3.970000 (  4.328655)
Country.unscoped.map(&:name):   3.780000   0.030000   3.810000 (  4.159162)
Coutry.pluck(:name):            1.550000   0.040000   1.590000 (  1.879490)
```